# The Load balancer connection to the ecs service running fargate (both in the same private subnet) times out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a VPC with 4 subnets, two public and two private ones (one private and public in each AZ). I'm launching the ecs service with fargate tasks in the private subnets and assigning the ecs task a security group that allows incoming traffic from the Application load balancer's security group. The load balancer is of type internal and launched in the same private subnet. My cloudformation file looks like this:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: ECS task some server

Parameters:
  VpcId:
    Type: String
  VpcCidr:
    Type: String
  SubnetIds:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList # private subnets
  Cluster:
    Type: String
  ServiceName:
    Type: String
  ContainerPort:
    Type: String

  # ENVIRONMENT VARS
  Image:
    Type: String
  DBUrl: 
    Type: String
  DBUser:
    Type: String
  DBPassword:
    Type: String
    NoEcho: true

Resources:
  LogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub /ecs/${ServiceName}
      RetentionInDays: '1827' # 5 years

  ExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub ${ServiceName}-ExecutionRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
          Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: ECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                # download images from ECR
                - ecr:GetAuthorizationToken
                - ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability
                - ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer
                - ecr:BatchGetImage

                # upload logs to CloudWatch
                - logs:CreateLogStream
                - logs:PutLogEvents
              Resource: '*'

  TaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub ${ServiceName}-TaskRole
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
              - ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
          Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: ECSTaskRolePolicy
          PolicyDocument:
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
                - appsync:GraphQL
              Resource:
                - '*'

  TaskDefinition: 
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    DependsOn: 
      - LogGroup
    Properties:
      Family: !Ref ServiceName
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE

      Cpu: 1024 # .25 vCPU (256/512/1024/2048/4096)
      Memory: 8GB # (0.5GB/1GB/2GB/.../30GB)

      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref TaskRole

      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Ref ServiceName
          Image: !Ref Image
          PortMappings:
          - ContainerPort: !Ref ContainerPort
          Environment:
          - Name: LOG_LEVEL
            Value: debug
          - Name: DBURL
            Value: !Sub jdbc:mysql://${DBUrl}:3306/db
          - Name: DBUSER
            Value: !Ref DBUser
          - Name: DBPASSWORD
            Value: !Ref DBPassword
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
              awslogs-group: !Ref LogGroup
              awslogs-stream-prefix: !Ref ServiceName

  LoadBalancerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: !Sub ${ServiceName}-loadbalancer
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: !Ref ContainerPort
        ToPort: !Ref ContainerPort
        CidrIp: !Ref VpcCidr

  ContainerSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: !Sub ${ServiceName}-container
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref LoadBalancerSecurityGroup
        FromPort: 0
        ToPort: 65535

  TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      TargetType: ip
      Name: !Ref ServiceName
      Port: !Ref ContainerPort
      Protocol: HTTP
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      HealthCheckPath: /healthcheck
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP

  LoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Type: application
      IpAddressType: ipv4
      Scheme: internal
      Subnets: !Ref SubnetIds
      SecurityGroups: 
        - !Ref LoadBalancerSecurityGroup

  Listener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup
          Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
      Port: !Ref ContainerPort
      Protocol: HTTP

  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: Listener
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Ref ServiceName
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          Subnets: !Ref SubnetIds
          SecurityGroups:
            - !Ref ContainerSecurityGroup
      LoadBalancers:
        - ContainerName: !Ref ServiceName
          ContainerPort: !Ref ContainerPort
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref TargetGroup

Outputs:
  LoadBalancerArn:
    Value: !Ref LoadBalancer
  LoadBalancerDNS:
    Value: !GetAtt LoadBalancer.DNSName
  LoadbalancerName:
    Value: !GetAtt LoadBalancer.LoadBalancerName
```

The healthcheck url is certainly correct, it's on the same port as the container and returns a 200 status code. But for some reason the load balancer target keeps timing out, I might be missing something here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try with an `HealthCheckGracePeriodSeconds` of let's say `300` in `AWS::ECS::Service`? It could be that your task takes some time to be healthy.

Comment: oh man, this was it! a thousand thanks, it was driving me crazy haha!